# xhr requests getting canceled and same requests get called automatically and getting succeeded

Tags: .net-core, xmlhttprequest, cancellation, cancellationtokensource, cancellation-token

In my application, after the page load (refresh) - xhr requests are getting canceled and automatically same requests get called again and that are getting succeeded.

I am trying to fetch data from the database in these calls, below is the code snippet.

```
public async Task<IReadOnlyCollection<ABCModel>> Get(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        using var unitOfWork = _unitOfWorkFactory.Create();

        var abcRepo = unitOfWork.GetRepository<ABC>();

        return await abcRepo.AsQueryable()
            .Select(c => new ABCModel
            {
                Id = c.Id,
                Code = c.Code
            })
            .OrderBy(c => c.Code)
            .ToArrayAsync(cancellationToken);
    }
```

[image]

Why I am getting this error. Help me solve this error.

Comment: Are the initial requests `HEAD` requests?

Comment: I don't think so